# Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate Auto Renew with Certbot on Amazon Lightsail Server running Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-web-services, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm trying to set up SSL Certificate auto renewal on my boss's Amazon LightSail server. It was previously set up by a past contractor who isn't being a lot of help. I am very unfamiliar with Let's Encrypt so I searched for an article. I found [this](https://www.onepagezen.com/letsencrypt-auto-renew-certbot-apache/) guide on how to renew it. I followed the steps up to step 4 but the script that it says to add to my crontab file is for apache. When I checked the conf file in the renewal folder, it shows that the installer used was nginx and that the authenticator is standalone. In this case, how would I be able to modify the script to set an auto renewal for the SSL certificate.

Here's the script: 45 2 * * 6 cd /etc/letsencrypt/ && ./certbot-auto renew && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

The Let's Encrypt folks have created guides for most combinations of operating systems and web servers.

Here is their guide for Ubuntu 16 & nginx:
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx.html

I would use a cronjob that looks something like this:

```
0 * * * * /full/path/to/certbot-auto renew && service nginx restart
```

Test out the commands before you create the cronjob to ensure that they work. I use root's crontab. If you are using a different user you might need to add sudo to the commands.

Change the frequency that the cronjob runs at to your liking. Let's Encrypt certificates last 3 months, so keep that in mind.

I force renew my Let's Encrypt certificates every 2 months before they even get close to expiring, but that is probably overkill.

Comment: Also, I keep trying to understand plugins from the certbot documentation. Technically, I'm running a server using Amazon Lightsail but the plugin used to install the certificate is nginx which, to my google searches, is a web server and much more. Is it just using a component of nginx to install the certificate and that's it? What are the advantages of using nginx over apache for example or does it not really matter?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337530/difference-between-certbot-and-certbot-auto

Comment: It sounds like the previous contractor installed nginx as the web server. If it is working I would leave well enough alone and stick with the current config. If you want to verify that nginx is running there are a couple of commands you can use.

`ps aux | grep nginx`

This will show you if there are nginx processes running.

`netstat -nlp | grep nginx`

This will show you the ports that nginx is listening on. I would expect it to be listening on 80 ad 443.

Comment: Actually, the contractor uses a Python Daphne server instead of nginx. This is what really confuses me about him using ngninx as an installer for certbot. His directions to renew the server are actually running this command. 'sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer nginx -d example.com --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"' and then copying over the new certificates over to the daphne server/django folder.

Comment: Have you been able to renew the certs by following the instructions he provided? If you are able to do it manually you could write a shell script that performs the same steps and execute that script with a cron job.

Comment: The thing is, when I run the command, it prompts an interactive shell where I have to manually respond with inputs. I may be remembering this incorrectly but I'm pretty sure cron jobs can't automate if a command includes an interactive shell and if it can, I don't know how to automate that. I tried running the cron job but it didn't work.

Comment: What happens if you run the command `sudo certbot renew` ? I usually use certbot with nginx or apache servers, so I'm afraid I might not be able to answer all of your questions. In my experience, once a cert has been issued, renewing it is pretty simple. This might not be the case with your setup though. Either way, there is probably some command you could run that doesn't require user interaction. Once you establish what that is, a script can handle the rest.

Comment: The previous contractor finally answered my email. He says, "that was one of the few webservers that certbot worked with at the time.  So I ran it and allowed it to copy the certificate files to where nginx would expect them and then just copied the files to where the Python code needed them.  Nginx is not used at all and as long as it's directory structure is there this process should be fine.  Certbot is more capable now so using the nginx structure might not even be needed anymore."

Comment: When I run that, I get an output saying that the certs are not due for renewal yet. With '--dry-run', the command causes an error. It first says that it's running pre-hook command: service nginx stop and then this error  'nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"'. Attempting to renew cert (prod.thefelixapps.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf produced an unexpected error: nginx restart failed: . Skipping. All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (failure)